# localhost not showing any xampp server

Tags: php

I have installed xampp on Windows7(64bit).I want to work with PHP, Apache and MySql. The server Apache and the MySql services are running properly on the Xampp control panel. But when I run the localhost on my web browser it just shows object not found. what should i do

Comment: If you have Skype installed. Then change the port of skype. Skype > Tools > Options > Advanced > Connections and untick use port 80 and 443